# On the conjugates of $1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}m}$.

Why does the as $\alpha_i$ runs through the $\varphi(m)$ conjugates of $\omega$, then $1-\alpha_i$ runs through the conjugates of $1-\omega$?

Here a conjugate of $\omega$ denotes a root of the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Why have $\omega$ and $1-\omega$ the same degree over $\mathbb Q$?

Then: how can we find a link between the two minimal polynomials of $\omega$ and $1-\omega$? Maybe this could be a point where to start.

Comment: I didn't mean the complex conjugate. See my edit.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's better to tell ;-)

Comment: What is $\alpha_i$?  You've not defined it.

Comment: No. I defined it: it's a conjugate of $\omega$.

Comment: The conjugates of a number over $\mathbf Q$ are the roots of that number's minimal polyomial over $\mathbf Q$. So if $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of a number $\omega$, what is the minimal polynomial of $1-\omega$? It is $(-1)^nf(1-x)$, where $n = \deg f$. Without using explicit minimal polynomials, the degree of a number over $\mathbf Q$ is the dimension of the field it generates over $\mathbf Q$. Since $\mathbf Q(\omega) = \mathbf Q(1-\omega)$, $\omega$ and $1-\omega$ have the same degree over $\mathbf Q$, as do $\omega$ and $a\omega + b$ for any rational $a$ and $b$ with $a \not= 0$.

Comment: Maybe just a little clearer to consider the minimal polynomial of $\omega-1$. It should be manifest that $f(X)\in\mathbb Q[X]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(X+1)$ is irreducible.